# Joining Table Relation into one output SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqLite and have two tables Profile and Option.  Profiles can vary from options depending on the code (see my example below). Basically users can create custom profiles and hence the code is different.

How can I pull profile options into options list so I have a single output?  The only relationship I have is based on code, but some profiles have codes not listed in options. I want codes not listed in Options to also be included and those that exist not be duplicated.

Code below see my comment on expected output.

Also created a fiddle here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/3e657c/1/0

```
CREATE TABLE profile (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, profileId INTEGER, value integer, type text, "name" text, "min" integer, "max" integer, "justment" text, "sortOrder" INTEGER, "code", text);
INSERT INTO "profile" ("id", "profileId", "value", "type", "name", "code") VALUES
('1','1', '0', 'c', 'John',  'test_001'),
('2', '1','0', 'c', 'Peter', 'test_002'),
('3','1', '0', 'c', 'Custom Record', 'cust_003');

CREATE TABLE options (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , value integer, type text, "name" text, "min" integer, "max" integer, "justment" text, "sortOrder" INTEGER DEFAULT 0, "code" text);

INSERT INTO "options" ("id", "value", "type", "name", "code") VALUES
('1', '0', 'c', 'John',  'test_001'),
('2', '0', 'c', 'Peter', 'test_002'),
('3', '0', 'c', 'Paul', 'test_003'),
('4', '0', 'c', 'Tim', 'test_004');
```

Expected Output single list no duplicates

```
|Name|
 John
 Peter
 Paul
 Tim
 Custom Record      
/*
```

Not sure if this is even possible, but appreciate any insight. Probably going to have to do this with a loop in PHP, but if there is any SQL way it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `UNION ALL` and `NOT EXISTS` in the 2nd query:

```
select id, value, type, name, code from options
union all
select id, value, type, name, code from profile p
where not exists (
  select 1 from options o
  where p.code = o.code
)
```

You can change the `select` list to return the columns that you need.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m2K4xKeWvKbLtgQdAMdcaA/0).
Results:

```
| id  | value | type | name          | code     |
| --- | ----- | ---- | ------------- | -------- |
| 1   | 0     | c    | John          | test_001 |
| 2   | 0     | c    | Peter         | test_002 |
| 3   | 0     | c    | Paul          | test_003 |
| 4   | 0     | c    | Tim           | test_004 |
| 3   | 0     | c    | Custom Record | cust_003 |
```

Comment: You are a life saver!  Thanks a lot for this , super helpful.  Very much appreciated.